# Javascript bitwise operators - explanation required

Tags: javascript, bitwise-operators

I'm using some code in JS and I bumped into these (unrelated) expressions:

```
1) var r = (d + Math.random() * 16) % 16 | 0;

2) return c === 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8);
```

I read some about bitwise operators but it does not help in this context.
Can somebody explain (preferably step-by-step) how do they work ? How this two expressions are logically evaluated and run ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: IT IS NOT a duplicate, I was asking for a concrete case/example! Your link is to a general lesson.

Comment: The first seems to just be a trick to truncate the number. `(2.34 | 0) === 2`. The second looks quite normal... what specifically are you having trouble understanding there?

Comment: There are many questions about bitwise operators here on SO and [across the internet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators). Please include what you have gleaned from that research you've done. Otherwise this question is "read this code for me". I mean you could just take each operation, make it a separate line, and debug each one to see what it does.

Comment: Note that the duplicate is useful to understand `r & 0x3 | 0x8` it doesn't doesn't seem to cover `... | 0` which is just a hacky substitute for `Math.floor`.

Comment: The second example looks more like a ternary operator

Comment: ... Otherwise this question is "read this code for me".  Exactly, if you are kind...

Comment: Do you have a basic understanding of binary representation? Not asking to be condescending, just trying to get a grasp of what kind of answer you are looking for.

Comment: Misusing the website and hoping someone kind is willing to satiate you doesn't exactly shield you from those trying to enforce the rules. In some cases someone may answer a question of this broad nature, however you shouldn't be surprised at the closure votes and rule-reminders.

Comment: `| 0` is a “type annotation” for an integer in JavaScript.

Comment: Right, either this is a duplicate, or it is off-topic.

Comment: No, I don't know much about binary representation... only basics.

Comment: `r & 0x3` produces a number composed only least-significant and next-least-significant bits (i.e., the `1`- and `2`-value positions in the binary representation) of `r`; it will either by binary `00`, `01`, `10`, or `11` (i.e., 1, 2, 3, or 4). The following `| 0x8` also sets the fourth bit (i.e., the `8`-value bit) to `1`. Exactly what part of that isn't clear based on the duplicate suggested? (Not a rhetorical question -- expressing what's different about your question versus the information already supplied in the proposed duplicate is necessary to understand and answer your question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First statement has almost nothing to do with bitwise operators.
It simply means:

- assign random number between 0 and 15 to r, but if variable d is undefined, give me 0. It uses math fact that modulo 16 of any number gives you a result in [0..15] range and bitwise OR with 0 is an identity operation with one exception. JavaScript logic of handling `undefined` dictates that without `| 0` when `d` is undefined you will get `NaN` as a result in r.

Second statement does use bitwise operators.

- `x & 0x03` is the same as `x BITWISE_AND 0011` and it returns lowest 2 bits of x. `x | 0x8` always sets 4th bit. So, c will be a `10..` where dots are the lowest 2 bits of r. Of course, it will happen only if `c` is a string and equals `x`.

I strongly suggest you read https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_bitwise.asp and do some experimentation.

Comment: Thanks a lot @AlexPakka !

Comment: Usually 3 only has the bottom *two* bits set

Comment: @harold, thanks! Updated my answer. I was in a rush... was thinking `& 0x7 | 0x8` while looking at `& 0x3 | 0x8`

Answer (score 1):

Basically you could do a brute-force approach and look which values are returned in an object, one for `c === ''` and `c === 'x'`.

```js
function x() {
    var r = (d + Math.random() * 16) % 16 | 0;  // the last or returns an integer value
    return c === 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8);
}

var d = 0,  // does not matter, because of % operator
    c = '',
    i,
    values = {},
    v;

for (i = 0; i < 1e6; i++) {
    v = x();
    values[v] = values[v] || 0;
    values[v]++;
}
console.log(values);

values = {};
c = 'x';
for (i = 0; i < 1e6; i++) {
    v = x();
    values[v] = values[v] || 0;
    values[v]++;
}
console.log(values);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Just wanted to point out, that `d` matters. If `d === undefined` you will get a different result.

Comment: @AlexPakka, i was assuming that `d` contains a numerical value.

Comment: Valid assumption, but then `| 0` at the end of line 1 would not make any sense. I have two theories: it was an interview question or the developer of this code wanted to confuse a future maintainer as much as possible.

Comment: @AlexPakka, it looks like that is part of generating a UUID/GUID. [source1](https://jsfiddle.net/briguy37/2MVFd/), [source2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/create-guid-uuid-in-javascript)

Comment: @NinaSholz wow. Vielen Dank für den Hinweis! I feel better now that I did not help anyone to cheat.

Comment: @AlexPakka, guys, it was a piece of an exam I've failed today.... :(